# Can the same keypair be used for holding ETH and different ERC20 tokens?

Tags: ether, erc-20, private-key, public-key

I have an ETH keypair.

- Can I hold ERC20 tokens with this ETH keypair also?
- Can I hold several ERC20 tokens with one key pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hold both ETH and any amount of any Ethereum tokens in your account which is accessible with your private key.

It's up to the wallet you use whether it's able to display all the tokens or not. But even if you can't see them in the wallet client/app/whatever you still have them (assuming they were sent properly to your address).

Comment: Except my answer was some half an hour before the other answer :)

Comment: Heh no worries. But in general the timing shouldn't matter. If a better answer comes a day after an accepted answer, there's nothing wrong with accepting the later answer.

Comment: Your is better though. Hence the change.

Answer (score 3):

Yes

You can hold any amount of ERC20 tokens with your ETH keypair.

You can hold multiple ERC20 tokens